# Can't reach REST API running inside a docker container from Flask API running in another container

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a flask API running with docker compose. The flask API also uses mongodb.So the docker compose spins up a mongodb container and builds the image of the api from the dockerfile and then creates container.

This is docker-compose.yaml which would spin up both the API from the Dockerfile and also run the mongodb

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  hardware-reservation-api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "7070:7070"
    environment:
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://mongo:27017/
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-slim

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app


RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 7070

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Another REST API is config-manager which is also spun up with docker-compose.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  config-manager:
    build: .
    container_name: config-manager
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the go.mod and go.sum files to the container
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .


# Download all dependencies. This step can be cached unless the mod/sum files are changed.
RUN go mod download

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build -o main .

# Expose port 4000 for the API to listen on
EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["./main"]
```

The flask api ***hardware-reservation-api*** tries to go a GET http://config-manager:4000/env-config

```
api_url = config.get('flask', 'config_manager_url', fallback='http://config-manager:4000/env-config')
params = {'path': environment_name}
response = requests.get(api_url, params=params)

if response.status_code == 200:
# The API call was successful
    response_data = yaml.load(response.content, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    return response_data, ""
else:
    val = f"Error: fetching configuration failed from config manager {response.status_code} - {response.text}"
    return None, val
```

But gets a timeout.

When I just have the mongodb running with docker and the config-manager with docker.Then I run the flask api locally but instead of config-manager:4000 I used localhost as hostname it works.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: The containers need to be on the same Docker network for them to be able to talk to each other using the container names as host names. Docker compose creates a separate network for each docker-compose file, so your containers are on separate networks. Try putting all three containers in the same docker-compose file.

Comment: docker-compose is meant to have all the relevant services in the same compose file.   The different docker containers is what it *compose*s.